# What is the difference between who closed the door and who did close the door?

Tags: past-tense, auxiliary-verbs, simple-past

I was teaching past simple and there is this exercise in which we have to conjugate verbs to the past form. I know that we add an auxiliary to make a question, but do we sometimes omit this auxiliary for one reason or another.

The question that made me wonder is with (who).

> Who did close the door?

or

> Who closed the door?

Comment: *Who did close the door?* looks unusual, though you might be able to contract a conversation leading up to it such as, "Nobody says they closed the door, but the door is closed so somebody must have closed it.  Who did close the door?". Meanwhile *You did not close the door* or *Did you close the door?* or the stressed *You did close the door* are fine

Comment: Drop the "did"; it is not necessary. When an interrogative phrase is subject, as in "Who closed the door?", there is no inversion and hence  no auxiliary verb is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bader EL-din,

From a usage (not a grammatical) standpoint, the form "Who closed the door?" is a simple question seeking information (the door is closed, and the speaker wonders who closed it).  The form "Who did close the door?" would be used for emphasis, as in this scenario:  Jimmy didn't close the door.  Alicia didn't close the door.  I didn't close the door.  Well, then, who *did* close the door?

Lune

Comment: Please avoid adding name/signature to the answer.

Comment: So i was reading about this issue and people were saying that i wouldn't use an auxiliary verb if i was asking about the subject, whereas i would use it if i were asking for the object. How much true is this ???

Comment: Bader EL-Din, the question "Who closed the door?" asks only about the subject (the door-closer), not the object (the door).  The interrogative pronoun "who" refers only to people, not objects, so this question can in no way be asking about an object.  The insertion of the auxiliary "did" in this question adds emphasis to the question, but the auxiliary in no way shifts the question into a query about the door.  I know of no English grammatical rule that fits the one your describe. Lune

Comment: I have looked in Longman Advanced Learners' Grammar and it said: that if the question word is the subject, the word order is the same as in a statement i.e. the subject comes before the verb: example: who has been drinking my wine?. (who = subject )  we use question word order i.e. an inversion happens or an auxiliary is added before the subject when the question word is the object of the sentence, example: who did Mary invite? (who = object)

Comment: Bader EL-din, True, but originally you didn't ask about "Who did Mary invite?"  You asked about the difference between "Who closed the door?" and "Who did close the door?"  Neither of these interrogatives involves an inversion that makes "who" accusative.  They can't be inverted, in fact, without yielding the nonsensical "Whom did the door close?"  (As an aside, your supplemental question should be written "Whom did Mary invite?" as the sentence structure calls for the accusative case of the pronoun.)  Lune